# ASP.NET MVC - Determine if field has an error in Razor view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm working on an input form in ASP.NET MVC. My input form looks like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Result", "Contact", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { role="form" }))
{
  <h4>What do you want to tell us?</h4>
  @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

  <div class="form-group label-floating">
    <label class="control-label" for="Subject">Subject</label>
    <input class="form-control" id="Subject" name="Subject" type="text">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="submit" value="Send" class="btn btn-primary btn-raised" />
  </div>

  @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
}
```

My model behind this form looks like this:

```
public class ContactModel
{
  [Required(ErrorMessage="Please enter the subject.")]
  [Display(Name="Subject")]
  public string Subject { get; set; }
}
```

I want to conditionally apply classes and structure based on whether or not the Model is valid. I also want to do it per field. My question is, in Razor, how do determine if the "Subject" property is valid, or if it has errors? Thanks!

Comment: Use validationmessagefor helper. A ton of documentation on it

Comment: What do you mean by "apply" ? ("to conditionally apply classes and structure")

Comment: I want to do something like `@if (Model.HasError("Subject") { ... }` is that possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As was said in comments and by @PeterB - for displaying validation messages per-input should be used `Html.ValidationMessageFor` method somewhere near with your input on a view. But I want to notice: you have a model but do not use it in your form. More of this, you have data annotations for client and server validation and labeling and don't use them on your view too.

Please check this approach for your view:

```
@model /*your.possible.namespace.*/ContactModel

...

@using (Html.BeginForm("Result", "Contact", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { role="form" }))
{
    <h4>What do you want to tell us?</h4>
    <div class="form-group label-floating">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Subject, new { @class = "control-label" })
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Subject, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "Subject" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Subject)
    </div>
}
```

This snippet should display the error message that you described in `ErrorMessage` property of `Required` data annotation after posting a form. You can find useful to enable an unobtrusive validation.

You can find an article about validation in [ASP.NET MVC guides](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/adding-validation).

P.S.: And don't forget to perform a server-side validation in controller (for example).

Answer (score 8):

While ValidationMessageFor is the standard approach for displaying validation errors, the following code does exactly what you asked for and can be useful in rare circumstances:

```
@if (!ViewData.ModelState.IsValidField("Subject"))
{
    //not valid condition
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the Controller you can use `ModelState.IsValid` to see if there are errors, and also `ModelState["nameOfField"]` to see if a specific field has errors.

In the View you can use `Html.ValidationSummary()` (show all errors, if any) or `Html.ValidationMessageFor()` (show error for specific control, if any). Examples are plenty, both on & off StackOverflow.